# How to exclude specific css file from aggregation

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

Is it possible to exclude a specific css or js from drupal'l css and js aggregation ?

For ex: Exclude custom-style.css from being aggragated ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Similar to Drupal 7, the setting `preprocess` key to `FALSE` will prevent a JS or CSS library from being aggregated.

```
mylibraryname:
  css:
    theme:
      css/custom-style.css: {preprocess: false}
```

Same works for JavaScript

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {preprocess: false}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

As documented on [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)